# WiX: how to add setup.exe to the existing MSI?

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I have a wix project which builds msi for my application.
This installer has upgrade code 1.

Sometimes It requires administrative permissions to be run.
That is why I'd like to add setup.exe which will run the msi.

The only one way I see to create Bundle.
I.e. 
1. wixproj builds MSI (upgrade code 1)
2. wixproj which builds bundle package including msi (p.1.)(upgrade code 2)

These projects have different upgrade codes. How it will work if run on machine where the old product already installed with upgrade code 1 and was installed without bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle upgrade codes are distinct from MSI package upgrade codes. Burn lets the package upgrade itself.